# Cookie dies after Browser restart

Tags: php, session, cookies

I set up the cookies on my site with an 1 year expiration date, but they die when I quit and restart my browser. Is the expiration date too high, or what can be other problems related to that?

My code looks like:

```
<?php
ob_start();

$_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $user_info['user_id'];
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] = TRUE;
session_write_close();

setcookie("COOK_USER_ID",$user_info['user_id'],time()+(3600*24*365),'/');
setcookie("COOK_LOGGED",TRUE,time()+(3600*24*365),'/');
?>
```

And in my `auth.php` I check both with:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] && !$_COOKIE['SESS_LOGGED']){ 
     header("Location: register.php?header=no");
     exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be inside all your files, not just `auth.php`

Comment: thanks. actually i'm including `auth.php` into every file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo in auth.php:

```
if(!$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] && !$_COOKIE['SESS_LOGGED']){
```

should be

```
if(!$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] && !$_COOKIE['COOK_LOGGED']){
```

And sessions aren't persistent because PHP sets the session_id cookie with a lifetime of the current session.

Comment: wow, again a stupid "question" from me! thank you, now it works :)